# Codeigniter form validation error message on custom function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a custom function for my form validation in Codeigniter.
Its hooked to the URL Helper, i achieved this by making a MY_url_helper.

The helper modification:

```
function valid_url($str) {
   $pattern = "/^(http|https):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
   if (preg_match($pattern, $str)) return TRUE;
   else return FALSE;
}

/* End of file MY_url_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php */
```

How i call the validation:

> $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image path', 'valid_url');

The language file:

```
$lang['valid_url']  = "The %s field must contain a valid URL.";

/* End of file form_validation_lang.php */
/* Location: ./system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php */
```

But it doesn't show any error message when submitting the form.
If i change the valid_url function to echo something on true and false, it will execute that. So it runs the function.

How can i make the error message appear?

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing validation errors to your view?  Add this line above your form in your view and see if it prints then.

`<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`

Edit:

A few things based on your reply...I've never actually used a "helper" function as a callback for validation...I've always defined the callback in the controller where the validation occurs.  Someone else may be able to elaborate on whether you can use a helper function as a callback.  You may have to declare your validation function in the controller.  You could also return the helper function from a callback you declare in the controller as well to keep from having to re-write your helper in two places.  That may work.

I assume you are loading the 'url' helper in your controller?

Also..per CodeIgniter's documentation...I believe you are supposed to append 'callback_' to the beginning of your function name in your 'set_rules' declaration.

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image path', 'callback_valid_url');`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: @andershagbard edited answer to correspond to your updated question.

Comment: valid_url is the only error not showing. The custom errors appears.

Comment: @andershagbard added more info based on your last comment to answer. Hope this helps...if not, I am at a loss.